# Folder in 32bit OS for 64bit application

Tags: windows

This may seems as a silly question but i remember once that a had an application of 64bit and installed it on 32bit windows 7. Then there was something like a virtual folder created and had all the files there. It was named VirtualStore or sth like this

Anyone know this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path is:

C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\

Answer (score 1):

32-bit applications that do not have a [manifest with a requestexecutionlevel element](https://www.codeproject.com/kb/vista-security/makingappsuacaware.aspx) are treated as UAC-unaware and if they try to write somewhere where they don't have access (Program Files etc.) the action does not fail because the [destination is changed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756960.aspx) to a special folder where the user does have access (%localappdata%\VirtualStore). This called file virtualization.